# Dictionary RUNTIME problem at python hackerrank question (noob question)

Tags: python, python-3.x

All test cases done except for one and that one had Runtime error..
I am not one-liner, because i am beginner..
Is there any solution for my level?

Here is my code:

```
n = int(input())
phonelist = dict()
for i in range(n):
    user = input().strip().split()
    phonelist[user[0]] = user[1]    
for i in range(n):
    ask = str(input())
    if ask in phonelist:
        print(f"{ask}={phonelist[ask]}")
    else:
        print("Not found") #RUNTIME Error at case 1
```

Problem Statement : [HERE](https://hackerrank-challenge-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/17161-30-dictionaries-and-maps-English?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAR6O7GJNX5DNFO3PV&Expires=1609848756&Signature=VboAOZWUWCDHzmH1cyoptqc%2BdTA%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3D30-dictionaries-and-maps-English.pdf&response-content-type=application%2Fpdf)

Problem Test Case(runtime error) : [HERE](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/17161/input01.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAR6O7GJNX5DNFO3PV&Expires=1609850973&Signature=DDdF9ziKh7O3dusOLCas0paD0FU%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of queries is *not fixed*, as mentioned in italics in the problem statement as well, so you need to keep reading until you encounter EOF:

```
while True:
    try:
        ask = input()
        if ask in phonelist:
            print(f"{ask}={phonelist[ask]}")
        else:
            print("Not found") #RUNTIME Error at case 1
    except: # break when exception in reading EOF
        break
```

See [accepted](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-dictionaries-and-maps/submissions/code/194308935) submission of this code.